# Linq to entity, using sql not in operator

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Hi
How can I write the following sql query by linq

```
Select * From Employee where EmployeeId not in (Select EmployeeId in orders)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try either this:

```
var query = from e in context.Employees
            let ids = context.Orders.Select(o => o.Employee.Id)
            where !ids.Contains(e.Id)
            select e;
```

or this:

```
var query = from e in context.Employees
            where !context.Orders.Any(o => o.Empolyee.Id == e.Id)
            select e;
```